# RecyclerView resetting chat backgrounds

Tags: android, mobile, android-recyclerview

so i'm developing a mobile chat application with a Firebase backend. The problem i'm having is that the resource background changes when i send a message for some...but not all recyclerview items.  which gives the following look:

[image]

Here is my onBindViewHolder within my adapter:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatViewHolders chatViewHolders, int i) {
        chatViewHolders.mMessage.setText(chatList.get(i).getMessage());
        chatViewHolders.mTimestamp.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm)", chatList.get(i).getTimestamp()));
        //IF IT'S THE USER
        if(chatList.get(i).getCurrentUser()){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity = Gravity.END;
            chatViewHolders.mMessage.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            chatViewHolders.mTimestamp.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            chatViewHolders.mMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));
            chatViewHolders.mContainer2.setLayoutParams(params);
            chatViewHolders.mContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
            chatViewHolders.mMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble2);
        }
        //IF ITS THE MATCH
        else if (!chatList.get(i).getCurrentUser()){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity = Gravity.START;
            chatViewHolders.mMessage.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            chatViewHolders.mMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            chatViewHolders.mContainer2.setLayoutParams(params);
            chatViewHolders.mContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
            chatViewHolders.mContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble);

        }
```

I think the problem lies within the OnBindViewHolder method but i can't seem to make any headway on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(chatList.get(i).getCurrentUser()){
        ...
        chatViewHolders.mMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble2);
    } else if (!chatList.get(i).getCurrentUser()){
        ...
        // chatViewHolders.mContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble);
        chatViewHolders.mMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble);
    }
```

change background of `chatViewHolders.mMessage` only

Comment: This has made it a little more predictable in that now the only RecyclerView item that is resetting is the  one before... So user match sends hello (bubble fine) user replies (bubble replaced by green) bubble for match.

Comment: post your layout

Comment: Right i've found the problem. it was in my ChatActivity but your answer set me on the right lines.  I had nested my timestamp value within the currentUser boolean which for some reason was making a double call for the Recycler Adapter.